# How to share a file to other people using google drive sdk?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to share the file using my code instead of Google drive web interface.

I have checked the API reference on below page, couldn't find any method to do it, is that because the SDK/APi doesn't allow to do it?
https://developers.google.com/drive/v1/reference

Thank you guys can give some tips about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

That is currently not possible with the Drive API but you can use the Documents List API to manage sharing: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#managing_sharing_permissions_of_resources_via_access_control_lists_acls

Comment: as today(Sep,2017), the link is invalid.